# How can I use regular dashes in S-columns?

Tags: siunitx

I would like to have the cells with non-number entries centered but I can't even figure out how to get `--` (or `---`) working and printed out.

The reason behind this is that I have several instances of the following:

- picture shown on the left
- 4 rows of data on the right, sometimes several bits are missing (in this case only *c*)

### Picture

[image]

### MWE

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
tikz,
siunitx,
xspace
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}\small
\begin{tabular}{ll}
\begin{minipage}{2.1cm}
\tikz \filldraw[thick] (0,0) rectangle (2,2);
\end{minipage}
&
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{3pt}}S}
\( a = \) & \SI{111.11}{\newton} \\
\( b = \) & \SI{2.22}{\newton} \( (\ast) \) \\
\( c = \) & {---} \\
\( d = \) & \( \alpha \)  \\
\end{tabular}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

Comment: You are (probably) getting the wrong end of the stick with the `S` column here. Normally, and for alignment, you want just _numbers_ in such a column.

Comment: @JosephWright Hm... I know. :/ Well since it is you, I'll edit the op with the real display of my data which clarifies the clusterfudge of the units and so forth.

Comment: @JosephWright Ok finished the edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Enclose them inside `{}`:

```
\documentclass[
a4paper
]{scrreprt}

\usepackage{
lmodern,
siunitx,
xspace
}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}



\begin{document}
\begin{center}
\begin{tabular}{r@{\hspace{3pt}}S}
\( a = \) & \SI{111.11}{\newton} \\
\( b = \) & \SI{2.22}{\newton} \( (\ast) \) \\
\( c = \) & {--} \\
\( d = \) & \( \alpha \)  \\
          & {---}
\end{tabular}
\end{center}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Of course an `S` column here does almost nothing.

Comment: @egreg true, it needs more arguments. Hope OP knows them.

Comment: Yeah yeah first time ever using an `S`-column here. :) Am looking into as I had to take a break and respond to you snobby elite users. :P